# Shuffling columns in a delimited file

Tags: python, csv, unix, awk, sed

I have a file:

```
$ cat test.txt 
a   b   c
d   e   f
x   y   z
```

I could do this in Python to shuffle the columns:

```
import random

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    with open('test-shuffle.txt', 'w') as fout:
         for line in fin:
             line = line.strip().split('\t')
             random.shuffle(line)
             fout.write('\t'.join(line) + '\n')
```

[out]:

```
$ cat test-shuffle.txt 
b   c   a
e   d   f
x   y   z
```

**But is there a way to do it on the command line? Maybe with `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, etc.?**

Also, if I want to only shuffle specific columns, is that possible on the command line too, e.g. if I only want to shuffle the 2nd and 3rd column:

```
import random

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    with open('test-shuffle.txt', 'w') as fout:
         for line in fin:
             line = line.strip().split('\t')
             first , second, third = line
             second_third = [second, third]
             random.shuffle(second_third)
             fout.write('\t'.join([first] + second_third) + '\n')
```

Comment: Seems like an answer using `awk` or `perl` would just be a translation of your Python code =D

Comment: @justhalf it can be done in one line of perl. (Whether or not it is in good taste to do so is debatable.)

Comment: Well, the Python code shown in the question can also be updated to be a one-liner, since most of the code is a boilerplate and IO. The main function is just: `random.sample(line.split('\t'), len(line.split('\t')))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention perl, but perl is a superset of cut, awk, sed. It's the Swiss Army Chainsaw of programming languages!

```
$ cat /tmp/test.tsv
a       b       c
d       e       f
x       y       z
$ perl -mList::Util -aln -F'\t' -e 'print join("\t", List::Util::shuffle @F)' < /tmp/test.tsv
b       a       c
d       f       e
y       x       z
$ perl -mList::Util -aln -F'\t' -e 'print join("\t", List::Util::shuffle @F)' < /tmp/test.tsv
c       a       b
e       d       f
x       z       y
```

Oh, the second part:

```
$ perl -mList::Util -aln -F'\t' -e 'print join("\t", $F[0], List::Util::shuffle @F[1..2])' < /tmp/test.tsv
a       c       b
d       f       e
x       y       z
```

Comment: ++ for Swiss Army Chainsaw. :D

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using coreutils:

```
xargs -l shuf -e < test.txt| xargs -l3
```

Comment: Very nice!

(For some reason, MacOS xargs does not have -l...)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'NR==1 {srand(); 
            for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=i; 
            for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
              {j=1+int((NF-i)*rand()); 
               t=a[i]; a[i]=a[NF-j]; a[NF-j]=t}}   
           {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s",$(a[i]) FS; 
            print ""}'
```